Coupon Collector problem iteration mean with $n^2$ coupons
In the Coupon Collector problem with $n^2$ coupons, I want to compute the following probability corresponding to the iteration where the process ends:
$$Pr[I\leq i]=\sum _{k=n}^i \frac{n^2! \left(n^2\right)^{-i} {i\brace k}}{\left(n^2-k\right)!}$$
Given the CDF, I tried to use the complement to estimate the average iteration count:
$$E[I]=\sum _{i=0}^\infty \left(1-\sum _{k=n}^i \frac{n^2! \left(n^2\right)^{-i} {i\brace k}}{\left(n^2-k\right)!}\right)$$
However, though I looked at the post where the expected iterations for drawing the max amount of coupons is derived, I can´t find a way to simplify the above CDF due to the lower limit of the sum. Also, I tried with partial evaluations and $FindSequenceFunction[]$ in Wolfram and it doesn´t seem to help. So, is there any way to approach this sum to avoid such issue?

Is your question specifically about evaluating this sum, or are you open to computing the expected value of number of iterations in a different way?

@wei Mainly I want to compute the sum as defined above. However, it can be rewritten in other forms such as the difference between the sum with $k\in[0,i]$ and $k\in[0,n]$
